# Java 1.7.0_67 api connection

Tags: java, java-7, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I am using Java version 1.7.0_67 and want to communicate with external API https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/ which is using TLS_v1.2 Protocol with cipher suites:

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1)
- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1)
- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048)

I have enabled stronger version of algorithms in Java by updating https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html

Request example:
https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination?lat1=40&lon1=-50&resultFormat=json&startYear=2015&startMonth=01&startDay=01&model=IGRF

When using Intellij Idea directly (run program, debug program) I get response with code 200 but when build jar and run with the same java I get “handshake_failure (40)”.
Here is a snapshot from [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEY0c.png)

Moreover I use BouncyCastleJsseProvider as Security Provider for Java. Without that even running/debugging via Intellij is not working.

My code

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);

    String httpsURL = "https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination?lat1=41.000485&lon1=-77.938029&resultFormat=json&startYear=2012&startMonth=01&startDay=10&model=IGRF";
    URL url = new URL(httpsURL);
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "BCJSSE");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    SSLSocketFactory fact = context.getSocketFactory();
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(new SSLHandshakeInterceptor())
            .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String ss, SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(httpsURL)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

}

Comment: Err, why do you use java 7?

Comment: Try `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2", "BCJSSE");`

Comment: @areus Not working ;(

Comment: @GhostCat if I didn't have to, I wouldn't use it

Comment: It is 2021. Trying to establish secure communication using outdated unsupported java versions is thr opposite of good engineering practices.